# JTabbedPane does not add more than 1 tab when using .addTab()

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jscrollpane, jtabbedpane

I am wondering why the JTabbedPane only adds 1 tab. When I use the method addTab and then reuse it to create a new tab, it overrides the first tab created. Here is the code:   BTW, most of the code that might be related to the problem is at actionlistener.

```
package com.james.client;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.text.Element;

public class Main extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    //JTextArea
    final JTextArea code = new JTextArea();
    final JTextArea lines = new JTextArea("1");
    final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(code);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    lines.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    lines.setEditable(false);

    code.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
        public String getText(){
            int caretPosition = code.getDocument().getLength();
            Element root = code.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
            String text = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            for(int i = 2; i < root.getElementIndex( caretPosition ) + 2; i++){
                text += i + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            }
            return text;
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            lines.setText(getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            lines.setText(getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            lines.setText(getText());
        }

    });

    scroll.getViewport().add(code);
    scroll.setRowHeaderView(lines);

    //JFrame
    JFrame window = new JFrame("MinecraftProgrammer++");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(1000, 700);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //JMenuBar
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu newfile = new JMenu("New");

    //JTabbedPane
    final JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.setBackground(Color.gray);

    //JMenu items
    JMenuItem classfile = new JMenuItem("Class");
    JMenuItem packagefolder = new JMenuItem("Package");
    JMenuItem other = new JMenuItem("Other");
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    open.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          try {
            JFileChooser chooseFile = new JFileChooser();
            chooseFile.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            FileFilter filter1 = new ExtensionFileFilter("Java Class", new String[] {"JAVA"});
            FileFilter filter2 = new ExtensionFileFilter("Text File", new String[] {"TXT"});
            chooseFile.setFileFilter(filter2);
            chooseFile.setFileFilter(filter1);
            chooseFile.showOpenDialog(chooseFile);
            String filePath = chooseFile.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            FileReader readFile = new FileReader(filePath);
            String fileName = chooseFile.getSelectedFile().getName();
            tabs.addTab(fileName, scroll);
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner fileReaderScan = new Scanner(readFile);
            String storeAllString = "";
             while(fileReaderScan.hasNextLine())
             {
                 String temp = fileReaderScan.nextLine() + "\n";
                 storeAllString = storeAllString + temp;
             }

             code.setText(storeAllString);
             code.setLineWrap(true);
             code.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        }   
    });
    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
    JMenuItem saveas = new JMenuItem("Save As...");

    //Compile menu bar
    file.add(newfile);
    file.add(open);
    file.add(save);
    file.add(saveas);
    newfile.add(classfile);
    newfile.add(packagefolder);
    newfile.add(other);
    menu.add(file);


    window.add(tabs);
    window.setJMenuBar(menu);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the JScrollPane "scroll" to the JTabbedPane. How many times do you construct this component? Answer -- once only. So you're only adding and re-adding the same component every time.

```
final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(code); // here you create scroll

// .....

open.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      try {
        JFileChooser chooseFile = new JFileChooser();

        // ....

        // you add the same component here
        tabs.addTab(fileName, scroll);

        // ....

    }
```

Since you can't add a component to a container more than once and see it in both containers, the solution is to create any components needed for the new tab *inside* of the ActionListener's `actionPerformed(...)` method each time you need to add something to the JTabbedPane.

Comment: @JamesL: yes give it a go. You'll need to create a new JScrollPane and JTextArea and anything else that you need to add. Consider doing this in a method. Great, glad it works!